# How would I modify this MWE to always have a blank page at the end?

Tags: blank-page

How would I modify the following MWE, which gives an intentionally blank page, to work always (i.e. not only for odd number of pages)?:

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}

\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
\par\vspace*{\fill}%
{\centering This Page Is Left Blank Intentionally\par}
\vspace{\fill}%
}

\AtEndDocument{\clearpage%
\ifodd\value{page}\else%
\blankpage
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\vfill
\fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\chapter{Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Note: I appreciate this is probably quite easy to do - but I'm very new to LaTeX and everything I've tried is throwing up errors.

Comment: do you just mean remove the ifodd test? `\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\blankpage}` ?

Comment: `\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\blankpage}` works, but how do I keep the empty page style (so there's no header/footer)?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `\ifodd` with its `\else` and `\fi`

```
\documentclass[twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
\par\vspace*{\fill}%
}


\AtEndDocument{\clearpage%%
\blankpage
\thispagestyle{empty}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```